# bootstrap embedded/inline datepicker show last month on setDates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/) and I'm trying to set dates (events) from returned array of dates, but when I set dates by using datepicker's method (setDates), It's shows the month of the last date in the array of events, how to let it return to the current month.

```
var events = ['02/02/2015','02/05/2015','02/09/2015','03/09/2015'];

    $('.calendar').datepicker({
                multidate: true,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6",
                todayHighlight: true
    });

    $('.calendar').datepicker('setDates', events);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nj55cfL/)

Comment: Not the best approach but you can enable the todayBtn and trigger click of that button after setting dates. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6nj55cfL/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6nj55cfL/2/)

Try this

```
 var todayDate = new Date()
var events = ['02/02/2015','02/05/2015','02/09/2015','03/09/2015',todayDate ];

    $('.calendar').datepicker({
                multidate: true,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6",
                todayHighlight: true
    });

    $('.calendar').datepicker('setDates', events );
```

Comment: not that what I want, you didn't set events on datepicker, I want to show events (active) on datepicker, but it should display February month, not March !